# Updating collection in EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, collections, foreign-keys

How you usually update collection in EF? 
Imagine, that we have some model `M1` with relative table, which EF presents as `ICollection<F1>` and can write code like `Entities.M1.F1.Where(...)`.

```
public partial class M1
    {
        public M1()
        {
            this.F1 = new HashSet<F1>();
        }
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<F1> F1 { get; set; }
    }
```

**So, what is the best way to update relative collection of `F1` with another one?** 

Simple assignment `Entities.M1.F1 = newData;` results data duplication, assignment with clearing `Entities.M1.F1.Clear(); Entities.M1.F1 = newData;` produces following exception:

```
An error occurred while saving entities that do not expose foreign key properties for their relationships. The EntityEntries property will return null because a single entity cannot be identified as the source of the exception. Handling of exceptions while saving can be made easier by exposing foreign key properties in your entity types. See the InnerException for details.
```

with the InnerException

```
{"A relationship from the 'FK_F1_M1' AssociationSet is in the 'Deleted' state. Given multiplicity constraints, a corresponding 'F1' must also in the 'Deleted' state."}
```

Answer (score 0):

currently there is no straightforward way to update collection in EF.
you need to go through each reference object and add/remove in collection.
f.x in this example below

```html
 var selectedCoursesHS = new HashSet<string>(selectedCourses);
            var instructorCourses = new HashSet<int>
                (instructor.Courses.Select(c => c.CourseID));

            foreach (var course in schoolContext.Courses)
            {
                if (selectedCoursesHS.Contains(course.CourseID.ToString()))
                {
                    if (!instructorCourses.Contains(course.CourseID))
                    {
                        instructor.Courses.Add(course);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (instructorCourses.Contains(course.CourseID))
                    {
                        instructor.Courses.Remove(course);
                    }
                }
            }
```

once you update this you need to make a state as modified for your context and then do savechanges()

hope this help!!!

Comment: Thanks. 
I'll wait a bit more, maybe another answers. 
This question is highly important.