# Update collection in Entity Framework in disconnected state

Tags: c#, entity-framework

```
class Parent
{
    public int id;
    public ICollection<Child> Children;
}

class Child
{
    public int id;
    public int childProperty1;
    public decimal? childProperty2;
    public string childProperty3;
    public Parent parent;
}
```

My code for attaching child entity to dbContext:

```
// Getting the DbContext
            DatabaseContext dbContext = dbContextScope.DbContexts.Get<DatabaseContext>();

            // Attaches the modified entity to context in disconnected architecture.
            dbContext.Parent.Attach(this.parent);
            dbContext.Entry(this.parent).State = EntityState.Modified;

            this.parent.children.Select(s => dbContext.Entry(s).State = EntityState.Modified);

            // SaveChanges
            await dbContextScope.SaveChangesAsync().AnyContext();
```

**Update:**
Added this piece of code insted of the `.Select()`:

```
foreach(var childEntity in this.parent.Children)
{
    dbContext.Child.Attach(childEntity);
    dbContext.Entry(childEntry).State = EntityState.Modified;
}
```

My dbContext is in disconnected state. I have to save the parent class and a collection of child class records say 5 child class records to the database. How can I achieve that? I have gone through these links:

[update disconnected object in entity framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1715141/update-disconnected-object-in-entity-framework)

[Updating collection in EF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29435451/updating-collection-in-ef)

[Storing a complex detached object graph in EF6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21677558/storing-a-complex-detached-object-graph-in-ef6)

Comment: `Attach` from the first link does not  work?

Comment: It works but only for the parent and not for the child properties.

Comment: Have you tried to attach child properties?

Comment: Yes. I tried that too. But it didn't work either.

Comment: Please add your attach/update code

Comment: @GuruStron, mentioned in my question. Please have a look.

Comment: Try adding `foreach(var child in this.parentEntity.childrenEntity){ dbContext.Children.Attach(child ); }` before the select.

Comment: Yes, when the select didn't work, I tried with foreach statement too. That did not work either.

Comment: Have you tried both? first attach then set state to modified?

Comment: What version of EF?

Comment: Entity Framework v.6.14